# Seccomp: Why does the following program deadlock?

Tags: seccomp

I have the simple test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <pthread.h>

#include <linux/seccomp.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

void *do_work(void *args) {
    prctl(PR_SET_SECCOMP, SECCOMP_MODE_STRICT);
    printf("OK.\n");
}

int main() {
    pthread_t t;
    int ret;
    ret = pthread_create(&t, NULL, do_work, NULL);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("Could not create thread, error is %d.\n", ret);
        return 1;
    }
    ret = pthread_join(t, NULL);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("Could not join thread, error is %d.\n", ret);
        return 2;
    }
    printf("Program done.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This deadlocks without printing anything in Ubuntu 16.04. From reading the documentation on seccomp, it is not obvious to me why this happens. Why does it? Doesn’t SIGKILL kill the entire process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the `printf` function.

If you run `strace -f` on your program (without the `prctl(PR_SET_SECCOMP, SECCOMP_MODE_STRICT);` line), you will see that the created thread call the `futex` system call.

The call to `futex` is forbidden by `seccomp` mode, so the thread is killed, so the `pthread_join` waits indefinitly.

If you replace `printf()` with `write(1,...)`, the program will behave has expected.

Comment: But why isn't the whole process killed? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/seccomp.2.html

Comment: Good question indeed, may be a bug report worth to be created?

Comment: Thanks. Then I haven't missed anything obvious.

Answer (score 1):

The created thread has a different process ID than the original thread (according to strace). Only the new thread is therefore killed when it violates seccomp. This means deadlock.